# Distributions as Features in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, feature-engineering, uncertainty, error-propagation

## The Problem

Let's assume I have a problem that seems perfect for supervised learning. However, some of the measurements I would like to use as features are not point estimates but are instead distributions representing my uncertainty about the measurement e.g. the output of a Bayesian model.

1. How do I use these distributions when training a model and later when I want to make predictions?
2. Is it possible to propagate the uncertainty of the features to the uncertainty of the prediction?

## What I've Considered

I've considered a few possibilities but none of them feel ideal:

1. **Use the Expected Value**. Create a point estimate from each distribution and use that scalar in the feature vector. This feels like I am throwing away valuable information e.g. it will treat `N(3, 1)` the same as `N(3, 10)`
2. **Use Percentiles**. Choose a set of percentiles (50, 97.5, etc.) and create a feature for each.
3. **Use Monte Carlo**. Build the feature vector by sampling from the distributions, creating multiple feature vectors for each observation. Not performant and I'm not certain this will produce meaningful results
4. **Use Distribution Parameters** Create a feature for each parameter in the distribution e.g. mean and variance for Normal.

Comment: If what the feature actually is is an uncertainty about the measurement, why not construct a small number of features targeting that directly, e.g., the standard deviation, the interquartile range, and the 90% - 10% range?

Comment: What are those distributions and how did you get them? Distributions is not something observable in real world, so I'm curious what exactly is your data?

Comment: @Tim thank you for your interest. In my case, these distributions are typically the output of a Bayesian model or Monte Carlo estimation

Comment: @JakeGreene so you don’t have distributions but samples from the distributions?

Comment: @Tim Sometimes they are samples and other times they are distributions e.g. the posterior is a Beta distribution